# How to access DOM in neutralino.js

Tags: html, dom, ui-automation, desktop-application, neutralinojs

I'm opening some webiste by simply using:

```
window.location.href = "https://someaddress";
```

in my neutralino app.

How can I access html (dom) of the viewed page and interact with it?
Is it possible in neutralino.js?

Answer (score 3):

You can access the DOM the same way you would in regular webpage.

For example: let myDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div") to select all div elements on the page.